# How to develop ads and ads free version (free+paid) of an app with same packageName in Android?

Tags: android

I created an app which is free and contain ads. 
Now i want this app in pro version with same package name that i can upload it play-store easily.

I just want to disabled the ads in app and publish as it pro(ads-free).

(Note- I need to keep the same package name for maintaining purpose)

Answer (score 1):

For this, you need to make your app use `In-App purchases` and create a one time payment for your paid version and manually handle the business logic for this in your app.

You can achieve this using `Modularization` in Android. Basically, you put your core code (the one shared by the Free and the Paid version) into the base Module and then create two `Dynamic Feature Modules`, one for the Free version which gets delivered at-install and one for the Paid version which gets delivered on demand and uninstalls the Free versions module. Carefully read this series of articles to understand how it works: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/dynamic-delivery (you can scroll further in the article by using the arrows at the bottom. There are also useful links to blog articles, Codelabs and videos on the bottom to help you further).

Comment: The store listing can either be paid or free. You can't achieve a free and paid version in a single app unless it has in-app purchases.

Comment: Good point, I forgot about this. Edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember you should use flavors in gradle or build types. Or using both of them.I do hope so.

Comment: This won't work for the same package name - you'll only be able to post one on the Play Store.